# Is there a list of default/user-generated matplotlib stylesheets/styles along the lines of ggplot and xkcd?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Rephrasing a previous question, I've seen several all over the place (https://github.com/tonysyu/mpltools), and I know ones exist by default in matplotlib (such as ggplot), is there a list any where?

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style module will tell you what is available if you ask nicely:

```
In [23]: matplotlib.style.available
Out[23]: [u'dark_background', u'bmh', u'grayscale', u'ggplot', u'fivethirtyeight']
```

`matplotlib.style.use` will also take *any* sort of path, including URLs as an argument.